# Coordinator layout with nested scrolling not working for add more than 12 grids?

Tags: android, gridview

I am using the below link example material grid for create the app:

http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/05/android-material-design-gridview.html

All of them works perfectly, but when I am adding more than 12 grids, its not scrolling and stuck with that.

Its one scrolls upto 12th grids not more than grid will be shows.

How can I solve? Can any one guide me?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the NestedScrolling and GridView for a RecyclerView.
Instead of using the Typical LinearLayoutManager you use GridLayoutManager(context , numberRows) and you will be able to scroll all you want through all elements your new grid.

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/